# How to set max height and fixed width for UITextView and force ellipsis rather than scroll if overflow occurs?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Here's my goal:

1. I want to use a UITextView rather than a UILabel because I want users to be able to select text and copy.
2. I want the UITextView to max out at a height of 60 points.
3. I want the UITextView to have a fixed width of 300 points.
4. I want the UITextView to line break on words.
5. Let's say, based on the attributed text string I feed it, that it takes 3 lines to reach the 60 point max height. Therefore, if I feed the UITextView 6 lines worth of attributed text I want the UITextView to max out at 60 points and display 3 lines followed by an ellipsis (e.g. ...).
6. I don't want the text view to ever be scrollable.
7. If I feed the UITextView a single word as attributed text, such as "Hello", I want the UITextView to still have a fixed width of 300 points but a dynamic height that scales to as small as it can be, approximately 20 points for a single line of text in this example.
8. I want the UITextView to have zero internal padding.

Any ideas?

Comment: Almost all of these issues are directly addressed by the `UITextView` official documentation, and the rest are indirectly addressed... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html

Comment: I have read the documentation extensively and have spent over 8 hours trying to code this. Yes, it seems straightforward, but it is hard to implement. I have been unable to do so and so am now finally asking for help.

Comment: If you've spent 8 hours on it, a good start will be including what you've tried so far, what of this long list of goals you were able to accomplish, and what you have left to mark off this list.  A LOT of stuff on this list is extraordinarily basic and straightforward, and while it's important to include all the requirements for what you need, as posted, without including your efforts so far, and your specific problems, it looks like you're just asking someone to spend an hour or two coming up with a custom control for you.

Comment: @nhgrif I posted my own answer. Is this the extraordinarily basic and straightforward answer you were expecting? I don't care for it b/c it requires munching the string to be shorter and shorter by 3 characters per cycle (while loop). Any ideas on how to make it more efficient?

Comment: For tips on making the code more elegant, I suggest posting your answer as a question at CodeReview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/objective-c Anyway, I wasn't suggesting that the entirety of the solution was straight-forward and basic, just that a lot of the aspects would be (line break on words, no scrolling, padding, etc, lots of already-existing UITextView properties), and that your answer included no shown effort at all (especially toward the simple aspects of this problem) made the question look like you just wanted someone to write code for you instead of ...

Comment: ... what you actually probably needed, which was probably just some help with the tougher aspects of this implementation.   (I'm not the downvoter, by the way.)

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is new to me, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString*)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width
{
    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:text];
    CGSize size = [calculationView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Invoke super
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get text of unknown length
    NSMutableAttributedString *myAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"String of unknown length here..." attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]}];

    // Get ellipsis w/ matching attributes
    NSDictionary *endCharAttributes = [myAttributedString attributesAtIndex:myAttributedString.length - 1 effectiveRange:NULL];
    NSAttributedString *ellipsis = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"..." attributes:endCharAttributes];

    // Define size constraints
    CGFloat maxHeight = 60;
    CGFloat fixedWidth = 300;

    // Get starting height
    CGFloat textViewHeight = [self textViewHeightForAttributedText:myAttributedString andWidth:fixedWidth];

    // Reduce string size and add ellipsis until we fit within our height constraint
    while (textViewHeight > maxHeight)
    {
        NSLog(@"%f", textViewHeight);
        NSRange substringRange = {0, myAttributedString.length - 6}; // Reducing by 6 works for my app (strings are never huge)
        myAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[myAttributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:substringRange]];
        [myAttributedString appendAttributedString:ellipsis];
        NSLog(@"myAttributedString = %@", myAttributedString);
        textViewHeight = [self textViewHeightForAttributedText:myAttributedString andWidth:fixedWidth];
    }

    // Init and config UITextView
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    textView.attributedText = myAttributedString;
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, fixedWidth, textViewHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}
```

Have a more elegant solution? Post it!

UPDATE: You can increase the performance of `- (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString*)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width` by adding a helpers class and implementing the the following class methods:

```
// Private, gets us to alloc init calculation view one time for life of application
+ (UITextView *)calculationView
{
    static UITextView *_calculationView;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    });
    return _calculationView;
}

// Public, app calls this a lot
+ (CGFloat)textViewHeightForAttributedText:(NSAttributedString*)text andWidth:(CGFloat)width usingUIEdgeInset:(UIEdgeInsets)edgeInsets
{
    [self calculationView].textContainerInset = edgeInsets;
    [self calculationView].attributedText = text;
    CGSize size = [[self calculationView] sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX)];
    return size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered subclassing UILabel and adding the capability to select and copy text? Mattt Thompson has a good example [here](http://nshipster.com/uimenucontroller/).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
- (NSString*)stringByTruncatingToWidth:(CGFloat)width maxHeight:(CGFloat)maxHeight font:(UIFont *)font;
    {
        NSString *ellipsis = @"…";
        NSMutableString *truncatedString = [self mutableCopy];
        if ([self textSizeForMaxWidth:width font:font].height > maxHeight)
        {
            truncatedString = [[truncatedString stringByAppendingString:ellipsis] mutableCopy];
            NSRange range = {truncatedString.length - 4, 1};
            [truncatedString deleteCharactersInRange:range];
            while ([truncatedString textSizeForMaxWidth:width font:font].height > maxHeight){
                [truncatedString deleteCharactersInRange:range];
                range.location--;
            }
        }
        return truncatedString;
    }
```

And help method for calculating text size for max width

```
- (CGSize)textSizeForMaxWidth:(CGFloat)width font:(UIFont *)font
    {
        NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc]
                                      initWithString:self];
        NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize: CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)];
        NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
        [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
        [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
        [textStorage addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [textStorage length])];
        [textContainer setLineFragmentPadding:0.0];

        [layoutManager glyphRangeForTextContainer:textContainer];
        CGRect frame = [layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textContainer];
        return frame.size;
    }
```